# Calling a Method on Lambda Expression

Tags: java, methods, lambda, expression

Is there a way to call a method on a lambda expression?

Consider following example where the reversed() method is called on MileageComparator:
`Collections.sort(cars, new MileageComparator().reversed());`

If I write MileageComparator as a Lambda Expression with a reversed() call however, I get an error when writing
`Collections.sort(cars, ((Car car1, Car car2) -> (int) (car2.getMileage() - car1.getMileage())).reversed());`
while it works fine without reversed.

I do know that I can simply exchange car1 and car2 for the same result, I would however like to know if a method call on a lambda expression is possible in general.

Comment: Using `(Car car1, Car car2) -> (int) (car2.getMileage() - car1.getMileage())` for comparison is a poor practice. Look into the `compare` method documentation for that in `Comparator` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression you have can be associated with many types like `Comparator` of `Car` type as well as `BiFunction`, so compiler doesn't know how to interpret `reversed()` method which haven't assigned to type

```
  Comparator<Car> carComp = (Car car1, Car car2) -> (int) (car2.getMileage() - car1.getMileage());

  BiFunction<Car, Car, Integer> biFun = (Car car1, Car car2) -> (int) (car2.getMileage() - car1.getMileage());
```

From java-8 you can use static method [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) with method reference operator, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing) with more examples

```
Collections.sort(cars, Comparator.comparing(Car::getMileage).reversed());
```

So by using [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) operator you can create `Comparator` object that sorts based on `mileage`

```
Comparator<Car> carComp = Comparator.comparing(Car::getMileage);
```

And then reverse it by just calling `reversed` method

```
carComp.reversed();
```

You can also [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method on list from java-8

```
cars.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMileage).reversed());
```

Comment: Thank you. So a method could only be called on another method encapsulating a lambda expression and not the expression itself?

Answer (score 3):

> I would however like to know if a method call on a lambda expression is possible in general.

It is not, because a lambda expression by itself is nothing.

The lambda expression is syntax sugar for implementing a functional interface. Without the interface defining the method signature, the lambda expression doesn't know what it is.

It's like creating an anonymous class using an undefined type name, e.g.

```
new Foo() {
    public void bar() {
        // This will not work
    }
}
```

That anonymous class will fail to compile if `Foo` doesn't exist.

Similarly, `(Car a) -> a.openDoor()` will fail to compile, because the compiler doesn't know what type is being implemented. To make it work, the compiler need to know which functional interface to implement, e.g.

```
Consumer<Car> x = (Car a) -> a.openDoor();
```

But the following will fail with error `Lambda expression needs an explicit target-type`:

```
var x = (Car a) -> a.openDoor();
```

When you wrap the lambda expression in parentheses and call a method on it, no functional interface can be inferred by the compiler, which is why this fails:

```
((Car a) -> a.openDoor()).accept(myCar)
```

You can however tell the compiler which interface to implement, by providing a cast:

```
((Consumer<Car>) (Car a) -> a.openDoor()).accept(myCar)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points.

You tried this and it didn't work.

```
       Collections.sort(cars, ((Car car1, Car car2) -> (int) (car2.getMileage() - 
                car1.getMileage())).reversed())
```

The Comparator is the same as the following:

```
       Comparator<Car> comp = ((car1, car2)->car1.getMileage() - car2.getMileage()).reversed();
```

Which won't compile either because the lambda on the right knows nothing about the `reversed()` method of the `Comparator`.

But you could have done this:

```
        Comparator<Car> comp = (car1, car2)->car1.getMileage() - car2.getMileage();
```

And then

```
       Collections.sort(cars, comp.reversed());
```

Because `comp` is a Comparator and knows about the `reversed()` method.

One final point.  It is not a good idea to use `(a,b)-> a - b` because subtracting values will not always yield the expected results.  It is better form to do `(a,b)-> (a > b) ? 1 : (a < b) ? -1 : 0`